# ERROR addOnPermissionsChangeListener: Neither user 10017 nor current process has android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS

Tags: android

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: addOnPermissionsChangeListener: Neither user 10017 nor current process has android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2013)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1959)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$LegacyClientCallbackAdapter.onReportServiceBinding(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:31)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0'
```